# How can I find network interface name based on vid and pid of USB

Tags: linux, networking, interface, usb, python-3.6

I'm using LTE USB Dongle.
I want to select special connected Dongle.

I have some code that find special USB Device base on VID and PID.
If find device, I must get this device's network interface name.

```py
def find_device():
    # find
    devices = usb.core.find(find_all=True)

    # if no devices
    if devices is None:
        print("No Init. Check your Hardware Interfaces")
        exit(-1);
    # else

    LTE = ()
    for dev in devices:
        for cfg in dev:
            for intf in cfg:
                if intf.bInterfaceClass == 224:
                    if (dev.idVendor == 0x1bbb) and (dev.idProduct == 0x0195):
                        print("===> Found LTE: Alcatel OneTouch L800")
                    else:
                        print("===> Found Wi-Fi")
                    print("===> VID, PID = 0x%x, 0x%x" % (dev.idVendor, dev.idProduct))
                    LTE = ('0x%x' % dev.idVendor, '0x%x' % dev.idProduct)
```

The code returns ('0x1bbb','0x0195') # this ID is Alcatel L800
Next, I want to find interface but I don't have a idea.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: you need to include a tag to show what programming language you are using. (`python`?). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Oh, my mistake. Thank!